# Only Square Textures loading correctly (Beginner question)

Tags: java, 2d, textures, lwjgl

(Sorry if this has already been asked, I couldn't find any other question or source describing my problem)

Okay so basically Square textures load and display just fine. [image: Picture of a Square tile with a Square texture]

But for some reason, when trying to load in textures that aren't square (and/or resizing the model so the texture fits) isn't working right.

[image: Picture of a Square tile with a 24x48 texture]
[image: Picture of a Rectangle tile with a 24x48 texture]

Here's the Player-bit:

```java
float[] vertices = new float[] {
    -1, 1.5f, 0,  // Top Left     0
    1, 1.5f, 0,   // Top Right    1
    1, -1.5f, 0,  // Bottom Right 2
    -1, -1.5f, 0, // Bottom Left  3
};

float[] texture = new float[] {
    0,0,
    1,0,
    1,1.5f,
    0,1.5f,
};

int[] indices = new int[] {
    0,1,2,
    2,3,0
};

model = new Model(vertices, texture, indices);
this.texture = new Texture("animation/player/idle.png");

transform = new Transform();
transform.scale = new Vector3f(16,16,1);
```

and here my Texture Class code:

```java
public Texture(String filename) {
    BufferedImage bi;
    try {
        URL path = getClass().getResource("/textures/" + filename);
        if(path == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Texture not found");
        }

        URI file = path.toURI();
        bi = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
        width = bi.getWidth();
        height = bi.getHeight();
        System.out.println(filename + ": " + (int) width + "x" + (int) height);

        int[] rawPixels = new int[width * height * 4];
        rawPixels = bi.getRGB(0,0, width, height, null, 0, width);

        ByteBuffer pixels = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(width*height*4);

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                int pixel = rawPixels[x*width+y];
                // Red, Green, Blue, Alpha
                pixels.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));
                pixels.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));
                pixels.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));
                pixels.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));
            }
        }

        pixels.flip();
        id = glGenTextures();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,id);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    } catch(IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void bind(int sampler) {
    if(sampler >= 0 && sampler <= 31) {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + sampler);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,id);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I am not using Slick or something like that, it's just plain LWJGL.
- I don't know what code I should put in here, just ask me if you need more

Comment: Presumably you've tried with the simplest non square texture you can think of and stepped through your code? What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: The Debugger doesn't tell me anything really worth mentioning, [this is all I get](https://i.imgur.com/9Fv0hdd.png)

Comment: That's not the debugger. Have you checked that the variables contain the values you expect at all states? If not, at what point are they different from what you'd expect from the simple texture?

Comment: I don't know about the debugger since that was the only kind of debugger I had. About the variables, they're all as they should be.

Comment: If the variables are all as they should be, then the code must work, right? You'll benefit grately in the future if instead relying on stragers to debug your code for you, you learn how the debugger in your IDE works and learn how to debug issues yourself.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, that's why I'm here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131281/discussion-between-tyyppi-77-and-dindinyt37).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your pixel lookup is backwards:

```
int pixel = rawPixels[x*width+y];
```

Should be

```
int pixel = rawPixels[x+width*y];
```